# Show Whole Leaderboard when going to Leaderboard

Tags: xcode, game-center

I am wondering if i can show all leaderboards instead of going to a specific leaderboard in gamecenter. I have my game now that whenever you hit the leaderboard button it goes to my default, but I was wondering if there was a way to show all on the button click.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it should solve your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view all of the leaderboards use this:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards
{
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The key difference here is that in my code I have

`gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;`

while you would have

```
gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault;
```